# cut text in td element on overflow

Tags: html, css

I have this table:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td style="white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;">
         item 1 item 1 item 1 item 1 item 1 item 1 item 1 item 1
    </td>
    <td style="white-space: nowrap" >
         item 2 item 2 item 2 item 2 item 2 item 2 item 2 item 2
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

What I want to do is: the right item must get all the space. If there is space left on the left side, the left item should be cut to available length.

I have tried `overflow: hidden` attribute but it doesn't work.

P.S.

I don't need elipsis

I can not use max-width on item 1 because I want the item 2 to use as much space as possible

Comment: Have a look at this, wouldn't this work properly, or do you not want it to go down? https://jsfiddle.net/edrx8ytu/ or https://jsfiddle.net/xogx2xzy/

Answer (score 2):

This might help you..

```
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td id='first'>
             item 1 item 1 item 1 item 1 item 1 item 1 item 1 item 1
        </td>
        <td id='second>
             item 2 item 2 item 2 item 2 item 2 item 2 item 2 item 2
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    #first{
      display:inline;
      overflow: hidden;
      width:30%;
    }
    #second{
      width:70%;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using media query,
Put this in your css code.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    #someid {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

And give same id in your html to item1

```
<td id="someid">
         item 1 item 1 item 1 item 1 item 1 item 1 item 1 item 1
</td>
```

Also you can change `max-width` as per whatever screen size you want instead of 500px.

Comment: But this is fixed length. What I want to do is a layout adjustable if the user resizes the window.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the table style `table-layout:fixed;` , which is extremely helpful when trying to force cell widths...

css tricks: https://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/prn2tkx6/

Comment: Thanks. The problem is, you have put 50% width for both itema. But what I want to do is: the right item must get all the space. If there is space left on the left side, the left item should be cut to its length

Comment: Are you sure table cells are the proper solution to your problem?

Comment: Feels like a horse before the cart situation - you'll probably have to add some javascript that recalcs the width of your 2nd cell on window.resize

Answer (score 0):

Write CSS styling as

```
<style>
table{
    table-layout: fixed;
}
td{
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
</style>
```